# Actualización de código en php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

tengo este código de una aplicación web de hace algunos años, soy muy mala en php y estoy retomando la aplicación e intentado actualizarla pero no me funciona y quería ver si alguien podría ayudarme a actualizar este código porque las funciones ya están obsoletas y cuando intento actualizarlo con mysqli me sale un error en esa sección y creo que estoy haciendo algo mal.

```
<?php

session_start();
require ("../clases/conexion.php");
$con = new conexion();
$con->conectar();

if ($_SESSION["correo"]=='') {
    header("Location:../index.php");    exit;
}
$sql_bus_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE correo='" . $_SESSION['correo'] . "';") or die ("Error al buscar usuario");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_bus_user)!=0) {
    $id_usuario = mysql_result($sql_bus_user,0,'id');
    $nombre_usuario = mysql_result($sql_bus_user,0,'nombre') . " " . mysql_result($sql_bus_user,0,'apellido');
} else {
    header("Location:../index.php");    exit;
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
?>
```

mi codigo de conexión

```
<?php

class Conexion {
    private $host = "localhost:3307";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $bd = "nutricion";
    private $con;
    public function Conectar() {
                return $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->bd) or die("Error al conectar al Servidor");

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Tienes que empezar por actualizar el código de la clase conexión misma, en el archivo `conexion.php`. Puedes optar por `mysqli` o por `PDO`. Yo te recomendaría PDO. Si no cambias la clase de conexión, es imposible ayudarte, porque luego todo el código que usa funciones `mysql_*` debe cambiar.

Comment: Si, esta con mysqli

Comment: Hay alguna pregunta ya en el sitio sobre cómo pasar de mysql_* a mysqli_* o PDO. Busca e investiga en el sitio y encontrarás la solución. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esta forma.

He escrito un código que sea seguro contra los ataques de Inyección SQL, y además que controle el flujo del programa, indicando los posibles errores:

```
<?php

session_start();
require ("../clases/conexion.php");
$db  = new Conexion();
$con = $db->Conectar();

if ($_SESSION["correo"]=='') {
    
    header("Location:../index.php");    exit;
}
if ($con){
    
    $correo=$_SESSION['correo'];
    
    /*Cambiamos el dato directo por un marcador, así se protege contra código malicioso*/
    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM tbl_usuario WHERE correo=?");

    /*Preparamos la consulta*/
    $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
    /*Pasamos aquí el dato*/
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$correo);
    /*Verificamos si no hay error al  tiempo que ejecutamos la consulta*/
    if($stmt->execute()){
        /*
           *Si se quiere saber el total de filas, 1º hay que usar store_result
           *Sí, mysqli es un tremendo rollo manejando resultados :)
        */
        $stmt->store_result();
        $filas=$stmt->num_rows;    

        /*Verificamos si hay filas*/
        if ($filas!=0) {

            /*Asignamos las columnas del SELECT a variables respectivas*/
            $stmt->bind_result($id_usuario,$nombre_usuario,$apellido_usuario);
            /*Llamamos a un método que nos de los datos*/
            $stmt->fetch();
            /*Cerramos el recurso usado*/
            $stmt->close();

        } else {

            header("Location:../index.php");    exit;
        }
        /*Cerramos la conexión*/
        $con->close();

    }else{
    
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$con->error;
}

}else{
    
    echo "Error en conexión a la BD, revise sus credenciales";

}

/* No sé que sentido tiene esta línea ¿  ? */

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

?>
```

---

### Clase de conexión

Este sería un ejemplo sencillo de tu clase conexión.

```
class Conexion extends mysqli {
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $db;
  public $mysqli;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->conectar();
  }

  private function conectar(){
    /*Aquí debes poner tus credenciales*/
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->pass = '';
    $this->db = 'db';

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
    /*Esta línea te podría ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza :-) */
    $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
    return $this->mysqli;
  }

}
```

**Modo de uso:**

```
$con = new Conexion();
```

Aquí, el objeto conexión sería la variable `$con` y  se asignaría inmediatamente, porque el método `conectar`  es llamado desde el constructor de la clase.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, lo intente y me genera este error 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Acceso.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\pages\Pacientes.php(4): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\clases\Acceso.php on line 16

Comment: @Analy  creo que estás creando mal la conexión en el archivo `conexion.php`. Si quieres [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/158954/edit)  poniendo el código de ese archivo para revisarlo.

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue.

Comment: @Analy hay error en tu código: `$con = new conexion();
$con->conectar();` 1º. La clase se llama `Conexion` con `C` mayúscula y tú la instancias como `conexion`. 2º. Llamas al método `conectar` que te devolvería un objeto conexión, pero no asignas el resultado de esa llamada a ninguna variable. Observa el ejemplo que puse al final de la respuesta donde dice **Modo de uso**. Y recomendaría que uses el modo Orientado a objetos, es más claro y más moderno que el modo procedural.

Comment: @A.Cedano en el ejemplo completo quizá debería hacerse tal cuál, el modo de uso de la parte final de la respuesta ya que al parecer usas la instancia para preparar la sentencia?

Comment: @Dev.Joel te refieres a cambiar `$mysqli`  por `$con`?

Comment: @A.Cedano después del `require` de la clase conexión , no asigna el resultado de `conectar()`  o me perdí de algo ?

Comment: Sí ya está corregido @Dev.Joel. Gracias.

Comment: @Analy cuando tengas resuelto lo de la conexión sugiero que pruebes con el código de la respuesta como está ahora, debido a que he tenido que corregir algunas cosas, como el uso de `fetch` para obtener los resultados, que no lo había puesto en la 1ª redacción de la respuesta.

Comment: Hola creo que si me funciono, ahora, tengo otro problema con otra clase del proyecto que al parecer también está mal. cree que podría revisar mi código?